# sphinxsearch returns "failed to send client protocol version"

Tags: sphinx

On some of my servers, doing a sphinx php query returns that error. Searching google I can't find anything except this is part of why the error came out:

```
// send my version
    // this is a subtle part. we must do it before (!) reading back from searchd.
    // because otherwise under some conditions (reported on FreeBSD for instance)
    // TCP stack could throttle write-write-read pattern because of Nagle.
    if (!$this->Send($fp, pack('N', 1), 4))
    {
      fclose($fp);
      $this->error = 'failed to send client protocol version';
      return false;
    }
```

The close I've found is this http://www.sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=4919

But I do not know where the sphinxapi.php is (I installed using manual compile) and not sure if that's a good idea.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had the same issue on my server, and I realized I did not start the searchd daemon at all.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all make shure that you use suitable ip for api library. 
What ip is using you can see into

sphinx.config section searchd{}.

If it is ok next step is to see sphinx status

searchd --status

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be with the wrong port. I had two ports set for listening in my `sphinx.config`:

```
searchd{
   listen = 9312
   listen = 9306:mysql41
}
```

When I've tried to connect via `9306` port, I got the error mentioned above. Changing it to `9312` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Sphinx 2.2.8

What I found is in this version the set of listen port in searchd configuration was removed and now the ports are

```
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
```

So when you configure the sphinx client use port 9312 works for me. Ie:

```
$sphinxClient = new SphinxClient()
$sphinxClient->SetServer("localhost", 9312);
```

Hope this helps you. And if you need more details about the basic configuration just ask me.